# How do I tag 'It Belongs in an Ancient Ruin'?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin) is too long to use, at 29 characters.  How am I going to tag [this game](http://itbelongsinanancientruin.com/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[it-belongs-in-a-ruin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-a-ruin) should be sufficient, hoping people will simply autocomplete the tag.

Answer (score 8):

[belongs-in-ancient-ruin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/belongs-in-ancient-ruin) is one choice, keeping all the "content" words.  It should be clear.  The problem is that if someone types in "it-" it won't pop up as a suggestion.

[it-belongs-in-a-ruin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-a-ruin) is *fairly* clear and will pop up as a suggestion if you type from the beginning.  It does, however, eliminate the suggestion for when someone types "ancient".

[it-belongs-in-an-ancient](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-an-ancient) is similar.  It's not a complete sentence, but I'm not sure that matters -- the truncation seems noticeable, which would lead the tagger to (rightly) assume that it's the game they're after.

I'm assuming [ibiaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibiaar) is not a well-known acronym.

I think you're kinda screwed no matter what; I would go with the third option ([it-belongs-in-an-ancient](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-an-ancient)), myself.  It only really hurts super-easily-confused people and fast typers who get in "ancient-ruins" before looking at the suggestions.

You could possibly have tag synonyms for some of these to help with the pop-up suggestions, eliminating any missed cases.

Comment: and the full name can go in the tag excerpt to help clarify whatever we end up using.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), I've gone ahead and retagged your question as [it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin).