# Increase tag length limit to 32 or 35

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Before you go and close this as a duplicate, I'm posting this as a new feature request because a lot has changed since the last time this was requested. There are now no technical changes necessary anymore to increase the tag length in a certain range. And there is [a precedent now on Literature.SE for an increase in tag length](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/351).

The arguments for allowing longer tags have been noted in the older feature request [Increase tag length limit to 30 characters.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/increase-tag-length-limit-to-30-characters) In short, almost all our tags are games, and games often have names longer than 25 characters.

The hard limit is now 35 characters, on Literature 32 characters were chosen. If anyone can find some examples where 35 would be a significant improvement over 32 I'd go with 35. Otherwise I think 32 would be a very noticeable improvement over the status quo already, and we could try that first.

Comment: How on Earth do the news spread that fast?

Comment: @Gallifreyan [blame napoleon wilson](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38062517#38062517).

Comment: I'll do some research on our tags after lunch to see if we have many tags that would need more than 32

Comment: @Dragonrage you can start with the questions on meta about tags…

Comment: I think it should be extended in the case of the tag for Ultra Street Fighter 2 which is for the game Ultra Street Fighter II: The Final Challengers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is now at 35 - **as of 8-8-2017**, [tags can be up to 35 characters long everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490).

Big thanks to everyone who jumped in here to help make this site a test subject for this change - if anything breaks now, I'll blame you!

Comment: I've renamed [tag:metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain] and [tag:mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword] as 35-character tests

Comment: So far looking at different questions with 35 character long tags, they all seem fine. I don't have any clipping on my pc (chrome browser). I'll check on mobile to see if anything breaks.

Comment: 35 characters fits pretty well on a iPhone 6s

Answer (score 11):

## Actioned

> These tags were raised as examples and have now been changed as a result of this meta post. If you want a particular tag lengthened, please raise it as a separate meta question so the community can vote on it.

- [rnc-qforce](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-qforce) -> [ratchet-and-clank-q-force](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-q-force) (25)
- [jk2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk2-jedi-outcast) -> [jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast) (26)
- [monster-hunter-gen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-gen) -> [monster-hunter-generations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monster-hunter-generations) (26)
- [scott-pilgrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scott-pilgrim) -> [scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world) (26)
- [rnc-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-all-4-one) -> [ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one) (27)
- [binding-of-isaac-rebirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-rebirth) -> [the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth) (28)
- [poker-at-the-inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker-at-the-inventory) -> [poker-night-at-the-inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker-night-at-the-inventory) (28)
- [sk-shinovi-versus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sk-shinovi-versus) -> [senran-kagura-shinovi-versus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senran-kagura-shinovi-versus) (28)
- [sk-estival-versus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sk-estival-versus) -> [senran-kagura-estival-versus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senran-kagura-estival-versus) (28)
- [touhou-pcb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-pcb) -> [touhou-perfect-cherry-blossom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-perfect-cherry-blossom) (29)
- [mgs-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-revengeance), [metal-gear-rising](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-rising) -> [metal-gear-rising-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-rising-revengeance) (29)
- [mgs-peace-walker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-peace-walker) -> [metal-gear-solid-peace-walker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-peace-walker) (29)
- [mgs-portable-ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-portable-ops) -> [metal-gear-solid-portable-ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-portable-ops) (29)
- [boi-antibirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-antibirth) -> [the-binding-of-isaac-antibirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-antibirth) (31)
- [boi-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth) -> [the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth) (31)
- [boi-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boi-afterbirth%2b) -> [the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth%2b) (32)
- [mgs-5-ground-zeroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-ground-zeroes) -> [metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes) (32)
- [nfs2se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs2se) -> [need-for-speed-2-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-2-special-edition) (32)
- [pvz-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pvz-garden-warfare) -> [plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare) (32)
- [rnc-into-the-nexus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-into-the-nexus) -> [ratchet-and-clank-into-the-nexus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-into-the-nexus) (32)
- [legend-of-zelda-collectors-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda-collectors-edition) (34) (New Tag)
- [mgs-portable-ops-plus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-portable-ops-plus) -> [metal-gear-solid-portable-ops-plus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-portable-ops-plus) (34)
- [ratchet-and-clank-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-2) -> [ratchet-and-clank-2-going-commando](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-2-going-commando) (34)
- [rnc-a-crack-in-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-a-crack-in-time) -> [ratchet-and-clank-a-crack-in-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-a-crack-in-time) (34)
- [touhou-eosd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-eosd) -> [touhou-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-embodiment-of-scarlet-devil) (34)
- [kiss-psycho-circus-tnc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiss-psycho-circus-tnc) -> [kiss-psycho-circus-nightmare-child](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiss-psycho-circus-nightmare-child) (34)
- [touhou-iamp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-iamp) -> [touhou-immaterial-and-missing-power](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-immaterial-and-missing-power) (35)
- [rnc-3-up-your-arsenal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-3-up-your-arsenal) -> [ratchet-and-clank-3-up-your-arsenal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-3-up-your-arsenal) (35)
- [mount-and-blade-wfas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-wfas) -> [mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword) (35)
- [mgs-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-the-phantom-pain) -> [metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain) (35)
- [wrath-of-the-white-witch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-the-white-witch) -> [ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch) (35)

Answer (score 6):

So looking at some of our meta posts on how to abbreviate tags that are over 25 characters, I found the following tags that wouldn't fit and had to be shortened. I also looked through all of our tags on the site and added ones not mentioned in meta posts (I may have missed one or two as we have ~4400 tags). Based on these, I would say push it to 35 (I really don't see us getting 110+ character tags anytime soon) as we already have quite a few games pushing that limit and developers apparently like absurdly long game names for some unknown reason. The tags that exceed 35 characters could be more easily shortened to 35 characters than 32 in some cases. Also, the amount of tags we have had problems with being over 25 characters shows that we need the increase in tag character length.

## 26-32

- [sly-cooper-thieves-in-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sly-cooper-thieves-in-time) (26)
- [star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes) (26)
- [magic-the-gathering-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online) (26)
- [shin-megami-tensei-persona](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shin-megami-tensei-persona) (26)
- [binding-of-isaac-antibirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-antibirth) (26)
- [jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi-knight-2-jedi-outcast) (26)
- [splinter-cell-chaos-theory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/splinter-cell-chaos-theory) (26)
- [need-for-speed-most-wanted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted) (26)
- [star-wars-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2015) (26)
- [sword-of-the-stars-the-pit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-of-the-stars-the-pit) (26)
- [minecraft-tinkers-contruct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tinkers-contruct) (26)
- [rachet-and-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rachet-and-clank-all-4-one) (26)
- [civlization-4-colonization](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civlization-4-colonization) (26)
- [x-com-terror-from-the-deep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-com-terror-from-the-deep) (26)
- [creeper-world-3-arc-eternal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creeper-world-3-arc-eternal) (27)
- [clash-of-clans-builder-base](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clash-of-clans-builder-base) (27)
- [player-unknown-battleground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-unknown-battleground) (27)
- [final-fantasy-record-keeper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-record-keeper) (27)
- [need-for-speed-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hot-pursuit) (27)
- [ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one) (27)
- [millennia-altered-destinies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millennia-altered-destinies) (27)
- [assassins-creed-brotherhood](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-brotherhood) (27)
- [assassins-creed-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revelations) (27)
- [affordable-space-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affordable-space-adventures) (27)
- [binding-of-isaac-afterbirth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-afterbirth) (27)
- [phoenix-wright-ace-attorney](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright-ace-attorney) (27)
- [stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl) (27)
- [assassins-creed-freedom-cry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-freedom-cry) (27)
- [blood-bowl-legendary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-bowl-legendary-edition) (28)
- [kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning) (28)
- [metal-gear-solid-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-revengeance) (28)
- [assassins-creed-3-liberation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-3-liberation) (28)
- [binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac-afterbirth%2b) (28)
- [space-invaders-identity-gene](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-invaders-identity-gene) (28)
- [command-and-conquer-generals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-generals) (28)
- [dynasty-warriors-strikeforce](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynasty-warriors-strikeforce) (28)
- [final-fantasy-airborn-brigade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-airborn-brigade) (29)
- [crisis-core-final-fantasy-vii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crisis-core-final-fantasy-vii) (29)
- [call-of-duty-united-offensive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-duty-united-offensive) (29)
- [it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it-belongs-in-an-ancient-ruin) (29)
- [command-and-conquer-red-alert](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert) (29)
- [assassins-creed-iv-black-flag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag) (29)
- [metal-gear-solid-peace-walker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-peace-walker) (29)
- [civilization-5-gods-and-kings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civilization-5-gods-and-kings) (29)
- [kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep) (29)
- [metal-gear-solid-portable-ops](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-portable-ops) (29)
- [story-of-seasons-trio-of-towns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-of-seasons-trio-of-towns) (30)
- [scott-pilgrim-versus-the-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scott-pilgrim-versus-the-world) (30)
- [team-fortress-2-man-vs-machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-fortress-2-man-vs-machine) (30)
- [the-typing-of-the-dead-overkill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-typing-of-the-dead-overkill) (31)
- [need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012) (31)
- [need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005) (31)
- [command-and-conquer-red-alert-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert-2) (31)
- [runner-2-legend-of-rhtyhm-alien](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/runner-2-legend-of-rhtyhm-alien) (31)
- [borderlands-handsome-collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-handsome-collection) (31)
- [plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare) (32)
- [sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion) (32)
- [command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-tiberian-sun) (32)
- [metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes) (32)
- [need-for-speed-2-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-2-special-edition) (32)

## 33-35

- [sonic-all-star-racing-transformed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-all-star-racing-transformed) (33)
- [might-and-magic-duel-of-champions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-duel-of-champions) (33)
- [rachet-and-clank-3-up-your-arsenal](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rachet-and-clank-3-up-your-arsenal) (34)
- [metal-gear-solid-portable-ops-plus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-portable-ops-plus) (34)
- [the-walking-dead-survival-instinct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-walking-dead-survival-instinct) (34)
- [metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty) (34)
- [dungeons-and-dragons-tower-of-doom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons-tower-of-doom) (34)
- [metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain) (35)
- [ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch) (35)
- [mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-with-fire-and-sword) (35)

## 35+

- [dark-souls-2-scholar-of-the-first-sin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2-scholar-of-the-first-sin) (37)
- [rachet-and-clank-full-frontal-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rachet-and-clank-full-frontal-assault) (37)
- [command-and-conquer-generals-zero-hour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-generals-zero-hour) (38)
- [kiss-psycho-circus-the-nightmare-child](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiss-psycho-circus-the-nightmare-child) (38)
- [fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-of-valentia](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-of-valentia) (38)
- [tom-clancys-ghost-recon-future-soldier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-clancys-ghost-recon-future-soldier) (38)
- [tom-clancys-splinter-cell-double-agent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-clancys-splinter-cell-double-agent) (39)
- [metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-the-patriots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-the-patriots) (39)
- [mount-and-blade-warband-napoleonic-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-warband-napoleonic-wars) (39)
- [mount-and-blade-warband-viking-conquest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mount-and-blade-warband-viking-conquest) (39)
- [dungeons-and-dragons-shadow-over-mystara](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons-shadow-over-mystara) (40)
- [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-special-edition) (42)
- [strong-bads-cool-game-for-attractive-people](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strong-bads-cool-game-for-attractive-people) (43)
- [command-and-conquer-red-alert-yuris-revenge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-and-conquer-red-alert-yuris-revenge) (43)
- [magic-the-gathering-duels-of-a-planeswalker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-duels-of-a-planeswalker) (43)
- [borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borderlands-2-tiny-tinas-assault-on-dragon-keep) (47)
- [dungeons-of-dredmor-conquest-of-the-wizardlands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-of-dredmor-conquest-of-the-wizardlands) (47)
- [the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy-30th-anniversary](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy-30th-anniversary) (52)
- [leisure-suit-larry-in-the-land-of-the-lounge-lizard-reloaded](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leisure-suit-larry-in-the-land-of-the-lounge-lizard-reloaded) (60)
- [mukashi-mukashi-aru-tokoro-ni-totetsumonaku-naka-no-warui-twintail-no-shimai-himesama-ga-irasshaimashita-to-sa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mukashi-mukashi-aru-tokoro-ni-totetsumonaku-naka-no-warui-twintail-no-shimai-himesama-ga-irasshaimashita-to-sa) (110)

Comment: Ah! Nice work going through all the tag requests! It'd prob be good to list the currently existing tag as well.

Comment: @Robotnik i'll try and do that when i have a few minutes. we have a lot of tags. i'll also update my formatting to make it a little easier to see which category questions full under like you did

Comment: @Robotnik i think I got all of the existing tags that were shortened but would exceed 25 characters if the full name was used.

Comment: Shucks, [tag:borderlands-2-assault-on-dragon-keep] is too long (by a character) too.

Comment: Great job! This was a helpful resource to test a number of 35 character cases

Comment: Quite a few of these tags have been actioned. Should I remove them from the list?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the already mentioned tags:

- [pokemon-oras](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-oras)
- [pokemon-sm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sm)
- [pokemon-hgss](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-hgss)
- [pokemon-frlg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-frlg)
- [pokemon-rse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rse)
- [pokemon-dpp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-dpp)
- [pokemon-bw2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw2)
- [pokemon-bw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-bw)

proposed changes:

- [pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire)
- [pokemon-sun-moon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sun-moon)
- [pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver)
- [pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green)
- [pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald)
- [pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum)
- [pokemon-black-white-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-white-2)
- [pokemon-black-white](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-black-white)

None of these tags are longer than 35 characters. The main goal of this proposal is so users who are less familiar with the abbreviations can more easily find the game they're looking for, and so they can interpret tags on existing questions more easily.

Comment: Well, we have a community wiki answer so I'm sure you're welcome to edit those in.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I mainly created my own answer because I couldn't be bothered counting how many characters each tag had before and after expanding.

Comment: @Nzall - Due to the lack of discussion or votes on this answer it might be worth raising this as a separate question - The abbreviated tags actually use the common Pokemon community agreed-upon abbreviations, rather than just a tag-limit-enforced abbreviation. - I'd want to see a bit more community consensus/discussion before we action these. (I was kinda hoping your answer here would generate that discussion but it hasn't).