# Do we really need a Revengeance tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-merging

While browsing tags, I noticed [mgs-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-revengeance). The game it refers to is actually called "Metal Gear Rising: Revengeance", not "Metal Gear Solid", but as I was about to edit it, I realized that maybe such a tag isn't even necessary, being (almost?) entirely identical to Metal Gear Rising.

Are the two games different enough to warrant two different tags?

Comment: According to the tag wiki, [metal-gear-rising] is actually the tag for Metal Gear Rising: Revengeance. It looks like the user who created [mgs-revengeance] just wasn't aware of the existing tag.

Comment: These tags are referring to the same game

Comment: In that case, should the tag refer to Revengeance or simply MGR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/181240), both [mgs-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-revengeance) and [metal-gear-rising](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-rising) have been merged and synonymized with [metal-gear-rising-revengeance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-rising-revengeance).