# Tag naming inconsistency for FF mobile games

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I recently picked up Final Fantasy: Brave Exvius, and wanted to ask questions on it. After not finding any suitable tag, I tried to use iirc **ff-brave-exvius**, which had to be edited by someone to the correct [final-fantasy-be](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-be).

Today I looked up the other mobile game based on FF chars, which is Final Fantasy: Record Keeper. Questions for this are tagged as [ff-record-keeper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-record-keeper) which makes the specific game name more prominent than the series (which imho is the better choice here).

I realize that most FF games don't really have a well used game name, or its still known more by the series number (e.g. **ff-a-realm-reborn** or **final-fantasy-arr** likely wouldn't be as recognizable as [final-fantasy-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-14))

However, in this case perhaps it makes sense to either rename the Brave Exvius tag to ff-brave-exvius, or at least allow that as a tag synonym so that it shows up when searching for a tag to use.

Comment: Ideally (and in most cases), when creating a tag use the full name of the game if possible. Given our [recent tag length increase](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/28182) it's possible most of the other final fantasy tags can (& probably should) be lengthened into their full names as well.

Comment: @Robotnik final-fantasy-brave-exvius and final-fantasy-record-keeper would be the most legible versions of both, and also they fit within the max tag length :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, when creating a tag, we use the full name of the game. The Final Fantasy games are generally pretty wordy in their naming conventions, and as such some had been shortened in the past to fit the 25 character limit restriction that was in place.

Now, given the [tag length increase](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12497/28182) these tags can be expanded if they can now fit under the limit of 35 characters. Thus rather than try and fit *Final Fantasy: Brave Exvius* to the short format, I think the best way forward is to expand them out into full names, and have the abbreviated versions as synonyms. As such, I've gone ahead and updated these ones:

- [ff-record-keeper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-record-keeper) -> [final-fantasy-record-keeper](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-record-keeper)
- [ff-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-tactics) -> [final-fantasy-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-tactics)
- [ff-tactics-advance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-tactics-advance) -> [final-fantasy-tactics-advance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-tactics-advance)
- [ff-tactics-a2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-tactics-a2), [ff-tactics-a2-grimoire-of-the-rift](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-tactics-a2-grimoire-of-the-rift) -> [final-fantasy-tactics-a2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-tactics-a2)
- [final-fantasy-be](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-be), [ff-brave-exvius](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-brave-exvius) -> [final-fantasy-brave-exvius](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-brave-exvius)
- [final-fantasy-ab](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-ab), [ff-airborn-brigade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-airborn-brigade) -> [final-fantasy-airborn-brigade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-airborn-brigade)

*Final Fantasy Tactics A2: Grimoire of the Rift* being the exception at 45 characters, I added an extra 'ff'-style synonym to account for the extra name. Given that the tag in use for many years was [ff-tactics-a2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff-tactics-a2) I'm sure people will find it easily enough.

Comment: Not sure if I missed any, please let me know if I did. And if anyone has any objections it's an easily reversible process. :-)